# how to join by centroid 2 shapefiles in r?

Tags: r, join, maps, shapefile

I am working with 2 shapefiles and struggle to join them. One is a 1 km x 1 km UTM sf (Universal Transverse Mercator ; containing different species richness numerical information (= Ab column & Sp column) and the other one is a municipalities sf . Both are polygon geometry type.
I would like to create a new shapefile with each utm1 **centroid** (and its related species richness information) assigned to the corresponding municipality. I know only one geometry can be kept so I would like to remain with the municipalities geometry. For some reasons I have a hard time figuring this out.

I manage pretty easily to create the centroid of the UTM sf thanks to `st_centroid` function

```
# Data importation : 
utm_sf <- sf::st_read("UTM01_Poly.shp") #sf with UTM1 square containing 
#UTM1_ID, its geometry and different related information (Ab & Sp)
muni <- sf::st_read("DGO3_Communes2001.shp") #sf with municipalities name
# and its geomtry


#centroid creation : 
utm_sf$centroid <- st_centroid(utm_sf$geometry)
```

I thought about using `st_join` but couldn't find a `join` argument that would assign each **centroid** UTM to the correct municipality.
Ideally I would like to end up with a sf similar to this :

```
 

| UTM_ID   | Ab       | Sp     | Muni_ID |Geometry |
| -------- | -------- |--------|-------- |-------- |
| 31UDS8   | 22       |10      |Namur    |POLYGON ((185960 93745.25, ...|
| 32UDS8   | 3        |1       |Namur    |POLYGON ((185960 93745.25, ...|
| 33UDS8   | 10       |5       |Namur    |POLYGON ((185960 93745.25, ...|
```

Do you have any clue on how I could achieve that ?

Eventually I would aggregate Ab & Sp by municipalities.

Thank you very much,
Have a great day

Comment: I've done this sort of thing with `st_join` - I think the default behaviour when you have points and polygons is to join on the polygons containing the points.  You don't need another join argument if each has a `geometry` (as long as the other names are different). You will need to have the same crs in each - use `st_transform` if necessary.

Comment: Actually, the problem might be with the way you are using `st_centroid`. Perhaps try `utm_sf_cen <- st_centroid(utm_sf)` and work with that as a point shapefile.